# Which one of these can be removed while clean installing

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, windows-update, windows-11

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR7dR.jpg

I wanna clean install Windows 11 but I don't know which one is which and which can be deleted without causing any problem like missing Asus Recovery. I did before in another company's laptop so I am a bit nervous.

Note Partition 4 and 5 are linux installed.
Also what is Partition 1, 2, 6 and 7 for? Can I delete them? I upgraded my laptop from windows 10. I am not thinking of turning back.

Comment: Windows 10 and 11 will create the 3 partitions it needs / wants.  UEFI, Recovery and Data.  So you can delete all partitions and install Windows 11.  If you wish to have the ASUS recovery, you can get the recovery key from ASUS, use that, and then upgrade to Windows 11. That will also work.

Comment: So I can delete all partitions without missing anything right? I don't know what ASUS recovery does but I don't want to delete it if I can't install it later. Can you send a link about how to do that? Also Can I just not delete Partition 8 which is MyAsus and delete all the other ones?

Comment: I think you can - just check the partitions carefully first.

Comment: Always make backups. Then make backups of backups. Then back your backups of the backups up.

Comment: Asus Recovery is unnecessary.  If you want to keep it upgrade to Windows 11 choosing to keep your files.  Without the required software to use the partition it's completely useless. anyways.  Also, "what is Partition 1, 2, 6 and 7 for? Can I delete them?", DO NOT delete them you will make Windows unbootable if you do. (Specifically 2).